# Indirect access column name with object variable

Tags: r, data.table

I have a straighforward problem, I need to access ne column with a dynamic variable object. How can I pass the `a` column indirectly? Thanks, below an example.

```
library(data.table)
a <- seq(0,10,1)
b <- seq(100,101,0.1)

dt <- data.table(a,b)
head(dt)

#access column "a"
dt$a

# indirect access to column a
var_obj <- "a"
dt$var_obj
```

Comment: `dt[[var_obj]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the vector you can do `dt[[var_obj]]`, to get a `data.table` of 1 column: `dt[, ..var_obj]` or `dt[, .SD, .SDcols = var_obj]`